# How to use inkscape command line interface?

Tags: command-line, windows-7, inkscape

I'm trying to use the inkscape command line interface. I have windows 7.

First I open up command line, and I run these:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Inkscape-0.48"
inkscape "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Pic\Class_UML.png" --export-png="C:\Users\me\Desktop\Pic\raster.png" --export-area=0:0:100:100
```

Then the inkscape popup opens, and I click embed, and then click ok, and then nothing happens, and the file doesn't show up.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I had about 54 SVGs inside a folder to be fine-tuned. I ran a batch image processing by selecting all SVGs inside the folder (using `*.svg`). Lolz it opened only about 10 I guess, after which my laptop rebooted...!

Answer (score 5):

On **Windows**, in the `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin` folder, you will see both `inkscape.exe` and `inkscape.com`. Use `inkscape.com`.

Here is an example from PowerShell:

```
> & "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.com" --help
```

Answer (score 4):

As of now, there doesn't seem to be a way to do **perfect silent processing** in *Windows*. However, any command using `inkscape` in **Windows** triggers an empty window while processing in background.

> If you don't want it to open separate *inkscape* windows everytime, try entering the inkscape interactive shell (using `inkscape --shell`).

**PS**: I don't think we can do anything more in interactive shell, more than what we can do using *cmd*. Hopefully someone solves the aforementioned problem in *Windows* and adds more functionality inside shell.

Comment: Is there a way to pass commands to that new shell and make that shell close it self (withouth ahk) such that the Inkscape commands can be executed silent and automatic?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to open the file C:\Users\me\Desktop\Pic\raster.png and see how it looks like?
Supposedly by using --export-png in the command line, inkscape will not open the interface but simply process what you requested silently.

In this case you should have the cropped image should be saved in C:\Users\me\Desktop\Pic\raster.png.

I use Linux and tried your example to test and I get the same behaviour you described plus the  response in the command line

```
Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00
Area 0:0:100:100 exported to 100 x 100 pixels (90 dpi)
Bitmap saved as: raster.png
```

Hope it helps

Comment: except for the fact that in windows for every request an empty window pops up and the silent processing happens; nothings received back on prompt;

Answer (score -1):

@echo off

REM setup Inskcape File Location

cd /d "C:\Program Files\Inkscape"

inkscape path\filename.svg --export-dpi=120 -e exported_image_name.png --without-gui